# YII2 передача данных в main layout

Tags: php, yii2

У меня в main layout есть часть кода которая должна получать массив с категориями или получать эти данные из БД.
Сейчас я их передаю через actionIndex:
    `$categoriesA = Categories::find()->all();`
    `return $this->render('index', ['categories' => $categories]);`
В index.php я их записываю в параметры вот так:
    `$this->params['categories'] = $categories;`
И уже в main layout я получаю эти данные. Но потом на других страничках возникает проблема что этих данных нет. Можно на каждой странице проделать тоже самое, но это каждый раз будет идти запрос к БД, да и как-то не очень красиво так везде писать. Хотелось бы узнать есть ли альтернатива моему решению чтобы в каждом action не обращаться к БД и в каждой вьюшке не писать:
    `$this->params['categories'] = $categories;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать свой собственный базовый контролер, и затем все ваши контроллеры будут наследоваться уже не от `yii\web\Controller`, а от вашего контроллера. В базовом контроллере вы можете переопределить конструктор, или метод `beforeAction` в котором вы сможете что-то выполнять перед каждым action'ом. Так же в базовом контроллере вы можете создать какое-то поле, а затем в него что-то записать в методе `beforeAction` или же в конструкторе. В layout'е, как и в любом другом view, вы сможете обратиться к этому полю через `context`

**Пример своего базового контроллера**

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\web\Controller as BaseController;
use yii\base\Action;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @var Category[]|array
     */
    public $categories;


    /**
     * Выполнять перед каждым action'ом
     * @param Action $action
     * @return bool
     * @throws \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        // Получить категории
        $this->categories = Categories::find()->all();
        // Вызов базового метода beforeAction
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```

**Пример обращения к полю $categories из layout'а и любого view**

```
<?php
/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $controller \app\components\Controller */

$controller = $this->context;
$categories = $controller->categories;
```

Но учтите, ваши контроллеры теперь должны будут наследоваться именно от вашего нового базового контроллера `app\components\Controller` а не от `yii\web\Controller`

Answer (score 1):

Создайте виджет и представление index в нем:

```
namespace ...\...;

use yii\base\Widget;

class CategoriesWidget extends Widget
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $categoriesA = Categories::find()->all();
        return $this->render('index', ['categories' => $categories])
    }
}
```

Потом выводите этот виджет в main layout:

```
<?= CategoriesWidget::::widget() ?>
```

Теперь, на всех страницах будет обновление.